# Allow restricted user to change their own password

Tags: linux, ubuntu, password, user-management

Recently I have followed the articles below, however, the `passwd` file that I copied to a dir in the users `‘home`` dir.

However, when the new credentials are parsed into `passwd`, it ends up with the error of:

```
Authentication token manipulation error".
```

I have googled alot, however none of the solutions has worked.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/65822

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498667/how-to-limit-user-commands-in-linux

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the password conforms to any complexity requirements?

Comment: Check the logs to find out why the password was not changed.

Comment: I am sure, because when you have a password that doesn't comply with the reqs, it shows an error.

Also, @MichaelHampton, mind explaining how i can view the logs?